# How to only plot edges above some minimum threshold value using markovchain in r

Tags: r, igraph, markov-chains

I have a large transition matrix that I want to plot a graph of in r. I have chosen the markovchain package to do this, which allows me to turn this matrix into a markovchain object and then plot it as follows:

`library(markovchain)
tMat = matrix(c(0,.2,.7,.1,.3,.4,.3,.1,.4,.5),3,3)
mc = new("markovchain",transitionMatrix = tMat)
plot(mc)`

which produces the following output:
[image]

of course, this is just an example, and as I mentioned before the real transition matrix is much hairier.

My question is: how can I plot only edges that have values greater than some minimum threshold? If I try to "zero out" all values below a certain threshold, markovchain complains that the rows do not sum to one (because it is then no longer a singularly sochastic matrix). But for a very complicated graph, it is less important that the edges connected to a vertex sum to 1, and more important that the graph remains readable. Is there any way to do this?

I know that the plot function is built on top of igraph.plot, so I am hoping that there is some option there that might help?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

-Paul 
woops: i answered my own question. Just wanted to leave this here in case other people encounter the same problem: you can simply create the markovchain object, and then go into its transitionMatrix attribute and edit the values directly: 
`mc@transitionMatrix[mc@transitionMatrix<.2] = 0`

which produces:
[image]

Now a god follow-up question which actually gets at the original problem and would be a better solution is: how to only suppress the numbers in teh graph output rather than deleting the lines altogether? It leads to ugly situations where previously connected nodes/vertices become islands. I think this would involve going into the part of the igraph.plot object that stores these values, which I don't know how to do even after reseraching quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to only suppress the numbers in teh graph output rather than
>   deleting the lines altogether?

Coerce the markovchain object to an igraph object; now you got all flexibility you need:

```
library(markovchain)
statesNames=c("a","b","c")
mc<-new("markovchain", states=statesNames, transitionMatrix=
          matrix(c(0.2,0.5,0.3,
                   0,1,0,
                   0.1,0.8,0.1),nrow=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(statesNames,statesNames)
                 ))
g <- as(mc, "igraph")
min <- 0.5
plot(g, edge.label=ifelse(E(g)$prob>=min, E(g)$prob, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Should give me enough to be able to answer my own questions going forward using the igraph documentation.